Algorithm to find the root of a graph represented as a tree?
I'm trying to write an algorithm that finds the (optional) tree root from a graph structure (SwiftGraph), that could represent any graph (not necessarily a tree). If a root is found the algorithm should return its index in the vertices list, otherwise it should return null.
This is my attempt:
Union-find by rank with path compression:
fileprivate class UnionFind {
    private var parent: [Int]
    private var rank: [Int]
    
    init(elements: [Int]) {
        self.parent = [Int].init(repeating: 0, count: elements.count)
        self.rank = [Int].init(repeating: 0, count: elements.count)
        
        self.makeSet(elements)
    }

    private final func makeSet(_ vertices: [Int]) {
        for i in 0..<vertices.count {
            parent[i] = i
            rank[i] = 0
        }
    }

    func find(_ x: Int) -> Int {
        if parent[x] != x {
            parent[x] = find(parent[x]) // Path compression
        }
        return parent[x]
    }

    func union(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
        let xRoot = find(x)
        let yRoot = find(y)
        
        if xRoot == yRoot {
            return
        }
        
        if rank[xRoot] < rank[yRoot] {
            parent[xRoot] = yRoot
        } else if rank[xRoot] > rank[yRoot] {
            parent[yRoot] = xRoot
        } else {
            parent[yRoot] = xRoot
            rank[xRoot] += 1
        }
    }
}

SwiftGraph extension:
extension Graph {
    /// If this graph is a valid tree, this algorihtm finds and returns the index of the root vertex in `self.vertices`.
    ///
    /// May require further testing.
    ///
    /// - Returns: The index of of the root of the tree, if this `self` is a tree, `nil` otherwise. If the graph is a degenerate tree,
    /// i.e. an empty tree, this function returns nil.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: **Time:** O(V + E⋅α(V)) where α(V) is the inverse Ackermann function, that grows extremely slowly (it is considered
    /// constant for any common practical application). **Memory:** O(V) to create the sets for Union-Find by rank with path compression.
    public func findTreeRoot() -> Int? {
        let unionFind = UnionFind(elements: [Int](self.vertices.indices))
        
        for vertex in 0..<self.vertices.count {
            for neighbor in self.edges[vertex] {
                let rootVertex = unionFind.find(vertex)
                let rootNeighbor = unionFind.find(neighbor.v)
                
                if rootVertex == rootNeighbor {
                    return nil
                }
                
                unionFind.union(rootVertex, rootNeighbor)
            }
        }

        var roots = Set<Int>()
        for vertex in 0..<self.vertices.count {
            roots.insert(unionFind.find(vertex))
        }
    
        if roots.count == 1 {
            return roots.first
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

Unfortunately though there are situations where graph.findTreeRoot() returns the wrong vertex index, that is, it returns the index of a vertex that's not the root of the tree.
What am I doing wrong here?
EDIT
An example of tests that fails:
let originalGraph = WeightedGraph<String, Float>()
        
for component in ["topbar", "secondary topbar", "gallery", "toolbar", "captions"] {
    let _ = originalGraph.addVertex(component)
}
                
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 1, weight: 1.2, directed: true)
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 2, weight: 0.5, directed: true)
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 3, weight: 1.1, directed: true)
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 4, weight: 1.3, directed: true)
        
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 1, toIndex: 0, weight: 1.1, directed: true)
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 1, toIndex: 2, weight: 0.5, directed: true)
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 1, toIndex: 3, weight: 1.5, directed: true)
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 1, toIndex: 4, weight: 2.2, directed: true)

originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 3, toIndex: 2, weight: 1.0, directed: true)
originalGraph.addEdge(fromIndex: 3, toIndex: 4, weight: 1.0, directed: true)
        
assert(originalGraph.findTreeRoot() == nil)

let msaOfTopbar = try originalGraph.msa(root: 1)
        
let msaAsGraph = WeightedGraph<String, Float>(vertices: originalGraph.vertices)
for edge in msaOfTopbar {
    msaAsGraph.addEdge(edge, directed: true)
}
        
assert(msaAsGraph.findTreeRoot() == 1) // assertion failed: 0 != 1


I don't really understand the problem. If your graph is a tree, finding its root is really trivial (it's the node that has no parent). If your graph is not a tree, there's no such thing as a root. Wouldn't it be easier for you to simply determine whether your graph is a tree or not first ? (if all nodes have at most one incoming edge, and if the graph is connected and has no cycle, then it is a tree).

@m.raynal: Of course I'm aware of your solution, but inspecting the inbound edges of a vertex takes O(E) raising the time to O(E^2+V)  which I don't want to.

"but inspecting the inbound edges of a vertex takes O(E)" I guess that's a consequence of this decision to store all nodes' edges in a single array that needs to be filtered down repeatedly. That seems like an odd way to represent it; does it has some benefits I might not know about?

@Alexander: It follows from the fact that I'm creating an extension for a library that I don't own, that is, I don't have a say on this.

@Bafforasta Fair enough, I was just asking because you might know, and I was curious. Could you explain how your current findTreeRoot() works in principle?

Not any graph but only acyclic graph can be represented as a tree.

@Bafforasta, inspecting the inbound edges of a single vertex takes O(E) time and O(1) space indeed. But, inspecting the inbound edges of all vertices in the graph at once can be done in O(E) time and O(E) space, all you need is to build the reverse table of your edges (O(E) time, O(E) space) and then inspect it (O(E) time). Since your graph already cost you O(E) space, and since you'll need to inspect every edge in your graph at some point, that's a cost you're already guaranteed to pay.

Moreover, 'counting' the number of inbound edges for every vertex of the graph is cheaper, only O(E) time and O(V) space. Just create an integer array of size V, visit all your edges and increment the counter of the edge source.
